# Проблема после сборки JavaFX приложения

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

не открывается страница приложения после сборки.
Вот код контроллера fxml от этой страницы, там ошибок нет и при компилировании в среде все работает, а после сборки в jar файле если перейти на эту страницу программа вылетает. P.S. там используется sqlite, пробовал отключить, не помогает.

```
public class DM extends Main {

    @FXML
    Button btnBack;

    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Integer> diagram;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        //Обработка событий по возвращению в главное меню
        btnBack.setOnAction(event -> {
            PageLoader("fxml_folder/main.fxml", btnBack);
        });

        XYChart.Series<String, Integer> pulse = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series<String, Integer> temp = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series<String, Integer> press = new XYChart.Series<>();


        pulse.setName("Pulse");
        temp.setName("Temperature");
        press.setName("Pressure");


        try {
            conn.Conn();
            conn.CreateDBT();
            conn.FillDiagram(pulse, temp, press);
            conn.CloseDB();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Отображение диаграммы
        diagram.getData().addAll(pulse, temp, press);


    }

}
```

Comment: а что говорит стэктрейс?

Comment: какая версия jdk?